# Conflicting retain types for property in object vs protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, memory-management

I've got a Core Data NSManagedObject called **Folder** that has a property "**account**" on it. Since this is an NSManagedObject the property is ***strong***.

I've then got a **FolderProtocol** that declares the property "**account**" strong as well.

Then I've got another object, called **FolderCombo**, that conforms to the **FolderProtocol**. The problem is I need to declare the property "**account**" ***weak*** on this **FolderCombo**.

An **account** has **Folders**, as well as **FolderCombos**. There is no retain cycle with the **Folders** since CoreData takes care of that (relationships use IDs not actual objects), but with the **FolderCombos** there is unless I specifically declare the "**account**" property ***weak***.

So everything works great **BUT** I've got a warning I can't get rid of. Can I/Should I just supress this warning? Is there a proper fix to this?

```
Warning: 'retain (or strong)' attribute on property 'account' does not match the property inherited from 'FolderProtocol'
```

Comment: I think you should change it to `retain` from `strong` the warning should go, if you have changed the default type though.

Comment: I would like to hear what are your reasons to define it as `weak` in the class that adopts the protocol. Being consistent -e.g., making it `strong` (or equivalently, `retain`) **everywhere** - will most likely save you a headache down the road.

Comment: @NicolasMiari If you read up above I can't have it be strong due to retain cycles. Also I changed it to retain and the warning is identical

Comment: Oops, sorry for not reading through! Yes, retain and strong are equivalent. Can't you make it weak everywhere, instead?

Comment: The standard way of avoiding retain cycles is to have a clear hierarchy in your object graph, and have "parent objects" hold strong references to "child objects" (and not the other way around).

Comment: No I can't make it weak because CoreData needs to have it strong on the NSManagedObject. Otherwise I will get the same warning only for it not matching weak in the protocol.

Comment: @NicolasMiari you're killing me man. That's my point! I need the parent Account to have a Strong reference to the Children Folders and the Folders to have a weak reference to the Parent!!!! In Core Data the relationship is strong because it is a reference and not the actual object.

Comment: You are doing the parent/children part right. CoreData only allows strong references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the property from the protocol and instead of that, require two methods, a getter and a setter. Note that the protocol methods can be implemented by a property (of any kind) but you won't have problems with `strong` vs `weak` any more.

Comment: This is a good solution. Mine is similar but probably more hacky. I will accept your answer as I believe your solution is more elegant and cleaner than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Well I came up with a bit of a hack to solve this but it works.

I created a weak private property called weakAccount.

```
 @property (nonatomic, weak) Account *weakAccount;
```

And then just made account `@dynamic` and overrode the accessors to return and set weakAccount.

```
 @dynamic account;

- (void)setAccount:(Account *)account
{
   self.weakAccount = account;
}


- (Account *)account
{
    return self.weakAccount;
}
```

This way the header file appears to comply with the protocol but the internal references are weak.